# persistence.xml not in jar after maven install

Tags: java, maven, ejb, ejb-3.0

I Created an ejb project in eclipse and converted it into a maven project.

and i created few files to connect to database but after running a maven install in the jar file i could not find my persistence.xml file.

But later after giving this piece of code in my pom.xml it worked fine

```
 <resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>ejbModule</directory>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

I just want to know what this is doing.

Comment: By default Maven copies files from ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources inside jar file. So looks like you have folders structure different from that standard layout. And with that piece of code you tell Maven to treat files except of *.java under `ejbModule` directory as resources and include into jar file

Comment: Ok thanks for the help @Ivan

Comment: Please don't start to use change the default only in cases you exactly know what you are doing...in majority of the cases the defaults are very good...

Comment: @khmarbaise i think this is the default folder structure when you create an ejb project in eclipse